# Could this center post be load bearing?

Tags: structural, load

[image]I have a partially below grade family room with a concrete sub-floor that we're remodeling.  There is a 12+ foot wide closet running across one wall.  I need the center post for the closet gone.  There is no dividing wall for the closet - just the post, which I'm guessing was just placed so two sections of 6 foot wide closet doors could be put in.  I will add photo.

It's a townhouse and all the homes here are basically the same.  I looked at photos of recently sold homes in the subdivision and I didn't see a post in that position in any of them.

Would we be safe in taking out this post?  The back wall is 2 feet behind the closet doors.  There are still posts at both ends of the closet, 12 feet apart, and we would probably leave the header up.

Comment: it could be. it appears to me made of wood, wood is a structural material.  what's above it? what's below it?

Comment: The load bering is in the wall behind it, the closet walls are cosmetic add ons

Comment: First move could be doing lots of visiting - neighbours - to ask if any of them have in fact removed theirs. There's bound to be one...

Answer (score 3):

Is that wall the edge of your unit? If so, it's unlikely to be holding up your ceiling two feet away from the edge.

You may, however, have two 6 feet long headers instead of a 12 feet long header. The width of the post seems about right for that. In that case, it would be load bearing in the sense that it's holding up your doors and part of the wall.